# To update all the records that are growing in number in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cron, rails-activerecord

I'm using MySQL, and Rails 4.2.3. I've a table called `onwers`, and it's gonna keep growing for 2 weeks, as there is background job that is feeding it all the time.

Now, I'd like to update all `Onwer` records in Rails, and the following is the way that I'm accomplishing the job:

```
Owner.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |owner|
  Owner.get_owner_details_from_github owner.login
end
```

What would be the best way to write code that will keep doing its job? On one hand, it's gonna populate `owners` table, and on the other, no matter how many records are there in `owners`, the code will do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be putting this code in a rake task and having a cron job run that task on some interval.

Alternatively you could use a tool like sidetiq: https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq.  It uses a daemon process (sidekiq) that runs perpetually and enqueues jobs on an interval you'd define.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not the point. The problem is that `owners` is growing each time, so it'd be a kind of race. In one jobs, `Owner` records are being created, and in the other job, the same `Owner` records are being updated.

Comment: Add a datetime column to the `owners` table named `logged_in_at` and set it to `Time.now` when doing the update. Have your update job only query for `owners` who have a `nil` for `logged_in_at`. Keep the update job running on a regular schedule and it'll continuously chip away at the new records. It would be better if your create job could trigger an event instead of determining what to update after the fact.